# What are the loss1 and loss2 in Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, loss-function

While training with `TensorFlow Object Detection API` , in `Tensorboard` I have found the following two plots called `loss1` and `loss2`. What these plots actually mean? Apart from these there is also another plot called `loss`. How `loss1` and `loss2` are related to `loss` plot?

[image: loss1 and loss2]

Comment: Please can you share the code, which you have used to create above visualization, without that it it not easy to conway what those are ?

Comment: @TFer2 it is just created with tensor-board. Tensor-board is a built in plotting functionality comes with TensorFlow. All you need to do just provide the path of `tflogs` directory. For example `tensorboard --logdir tflogs`. Then you will get an IP address along with a port number (for example `http://localhost:6006/`). Just open the link on any browser.

Comment: Yes, it was created using Tensorboard. My question over here is you must have executed some code (i.e TensorFlow Object Detection) to get these visualizations, please can you share those code or colab file ?